# $m = [K(\alpha):K], n=[K(\beta):K]$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$, prove that $K(\alpha + \beta) = K(\alpha,\beta)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I am looking for an elementary demonstration of this:

> Suppose $K$ a field, $\mathrm{char}(K)=0$ and $K(\alpha) \supseteq K$ and $K(\beta) \supseteq K$ field extensions. Denote $n=[K(\alpha):K]$ and $m=[K(\beta):K]$ and suppose $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Then $K(\alpha,\beta)=K(\alpha + \beta)$.

To let everyone know what my level is: I am an undergraduate math student and my interest sparked when my professor showed us the demonstration of what I have written above in the specific case $K = \mathbb{Q}$, which only works thanks the specific structure of $\mathbb{C}$.
I also found a paper that demonstrates it in fields with $\text{char}(K) \ne 0$, but involves subjects that are not in my course. [link](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-03/S0002-9939-1970-0258803-3/S0002-9939-1970-0258803-3.pdf)

I've tried to find mn distinct homomorphisms from $K(\alpha+\beta)\to E$ where $E$ is an algebraic closure of $K(\alpha + \beta)$. I've tried using the $mn$ homomorphisms from $K(\alpha,\beta)$, which has degree $mn$ over $K$, and I can say that my problem is equivalent of proof that: call $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ for $i\in 1,\ldots,n$ and $j\in 1,\ldots,m$ the conjugates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the other roots of minimum polynomial. Thus $\alpha+\beta$ has degree $mn$ over $K$ $\iff$ "$\alpha+\beta=\alpha_i+\beta_j\iff \alpha=\alpha_i\wedge \beta=\beta_j$".  My problem is that I don't know how prove that.

Thank you in advance

**Edit**: The specific structure of $\mathbb{C}$ is that, if you consider only $(\mathbb{C},+)$ you can orderer it in the following way:

$z = a + bi; w = c +di$ ($a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$)

$z < w \iff  a < c  \vee a = c \land b < d$

In that way we have a maximum $\alpha_{i} + \beta_{j} = \max(\alpha_{i}) + \max(\beta_{j})$. Now we have that:
 $$\sigma(\max(\alpha_{i}) + \max(\beta_{j}))= \sigma(\max(\alpha_{i})) + \sigma(\max(\beta_{j})) = \max(\alpha_{i}) + \max(\beta_{j})$$
If and only if $\sigma(\max(\alpha_{i})) = \max(\alpha_{i}) \land \sigma(\max(\beta_{j})) = \max(\beta_{j}).$ This lets us prove that there exist $mn$ distinct homomorphisms. Since $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha_{i} + \beta_{j}$ are conjugate, we can conclude.

Comment: Your link is broken. By an elementary demonstration, do you mean an elementary proof?

Comment: Also undergraduate math student doesn't tell us much about your background, since that can describe everyone from someone just out of high school to just about in graduate school.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jgon The link works for me. Anyway, I'm in my second year of an undergraduate math degree. I've done two algebra courses (the first one was during my first year and it was a basic course) on group theory, rings and Galois theory. They weren’t very specific, they covered the basics
And yes: I mean an elementary proof (sorry, English isn't my native language).

Comment: @James I've tried to find $mn$ distinct homomorphisms from $K(\alpha + \beta) \to E$ where $E$ is an algebraic closure of K(\alpha + \beta). I've tried using the $mn$ homomorphisms from $K(\alpha,\beta)$, which has degree $mn$ over $K$, and I can say that my problem is equivalent of proof that: call $\alpha_{i}$ and $\beta_{j}$ for $i \in {1,..,n}$ and $j \in {1,..,m}$ the conjugates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the other roots of minimum polynomial.

Thus $\alpha + \beta$ has degree $mn$ over K $\iff$ "$\alpha + \beta = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{j} \iff \alpha = \alpha_{i}  \land \beta = \beta_{j}$"

Comment: @James My problem is that I don't know how proof that (my comment was too long, I'had to cut it in two comments).

Comment: @Fillivan, I've edited the information from your comments into the question. That way future readers will be able to see it more easily.

Comment: Fillivan, can you tell what special properties of $\Bbb{C}$ were used in the proof your professor gave?

Comment: @Jyrki, I have added the structure and the proof in the question

Comment: Fillivan, I was somewhat hoping it would be about an ordering like that. You see, I'm somewhat optimistic about using that same argument in any field of characteristic zero. The zeros $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ span a finite dimensional space $V$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. An in a finite dimensional space we have a similar lexicographic ordering. Fix a basis, and declare a number to be smaller than some other, if its sequence of coordinates comes lexicographically ahead of that of the other. First check if the first coordinate lets you decide. If there is a tie, look at the second, and so forth.

Comment: Mind you, I haven't checked whether the argument goes thru.

Comment: I think that an ordering like yours required that you can order $K$ (or at least $(K,+)$).

Comment: Why would you need to order $K$ when you can use the ordering of $\Bbb{Q}$ (giving you the lexicographic ordering on any finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$)? Was there something else in that argument? Exactly how did it follow that $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha_i+\beta_j$ were conjugate?

Comment: @Jyrki, I did understand well your previous message, but something doesn't convince me. Why are you saying that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ span a finite dimensional space $V$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? I don't think that it is true. For example: $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}(x^{2},y^{2})$, but it isn't finite over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Jyrki, $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha_{i} + \beta_{j}$ are conjugates because they have the same minimum polynomial (to prove that we used that exist an homomorphism $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(\alpha_{i} + \beta_{j}) = \alpha + \beta$ and that $\sigma_{|K} = id$).

Comment: In your example $x$ has two conjugates over the subfield $\Bbb{Q}(x^2,y^2)$, namely $\pm x$. As does $y$. So the conjugates of $x$ and $y$ span a 2-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$ in that case. I was *not* discussing the field they generate but their *linear span over $\Bbb{Q}$*. Conveniently that linear span is stable under all the field automorphisms, because the field automorphisms are $\Bbb{Q}$-linear and permute those zeros.

Comment: But, I don't see why having that ordering implies that all the $\alpha_i+\beta_j$ are in the same orbit? Sure, each orbit has a maximal element, but why can't there be more than one orbit?

Comment: Actually, a smart choice of basis may take care of that. Need to think...